# ThreadLocal is returning null, even after being set in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor, thread-local

`ThreadLocal` in being set in `HandlerInterceptor` for each **request**, but sometimes it is returning **null** instead of the expected value, when accessing in the service layer.

As stated by docs **ThreadLocal** objects are **thread safe** and are local to a single request thread. So even if multiple requests are setting/clearing it, it will only get set/cleared for that particular request thread and not impact the request threads.

But 1-2 times(**not able to reproduce now, even with lot of logging statements**) in debug mode, I encounter that the `ThreadLocal` to be null in the service layer(thus got a **NullPointerException**), even though it should not be as it's being set in the `HandlerInceptor` which always hits first before the controller layer in spring-boot.

> Is below **ThreadLocal** code really thread-safe, when multiple request threads access it simultaneously.

Is it possible that **Interceptor** is executed in one **Thread** and controller executes in another thread and somehow controller thread executes first before interceptor sets the values in **ThreadLocal**.

Code :

**ThreadLocal.class**

```
@Component
public class ThreadLocalUtil {

    private static final ThreadLocal<ConstantsConfig> constantsConfig = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public static ConstantsConfig getConstantsConfig() {
        return constantsConfig.get();
    }

    public static void setConstantsConfig(ConstantsConfig config) {
        constantsConfig.set(config);
    }

    public static void clearConstantsConfig() {
        constantsConfig.remove();
    }
}
```

**HandlerInceptor.class**

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/health")) {
        return true;
    }
    // we are always setting ThreadLocal, before accessing it in service layer.
    setConstants(request);
    logThreadLocal();
    return true;
}

private void setConstants(HttpServletRequest request) {          
     ThreadLocalUtil.setConstantsConfig(BeanUtil.getBean(ImplConstantsConfig.class))
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {
    if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/health")) {
        return;
    }

    ThreadLocalUtil.clearConstantsConfig();
}
```

AccessorService.class

```
// accessed in multiple service classes for 1 request/response cycle.
ThreadLocalUtil.getConstantsConfig().getProperty1()
ThreadLocalUtil.getConstantsConfig().getProperty2()
```

Comment: Do you maybe use async or any similar tool that makes your service visiting another thread?

Comment: some calls to downstream are async where this is being used. Like they are being called in a different thread.

Comment: But to cover those cases I have also added ```InheritableThreadLocal```

Comment: Try a normal servlet filter instead. The getRequestURI() is not immutable but your code assumes so.

Comment: @BalusC, How filter is better then interceptor here. ```getRequestURI()``` is to skip this logic in ```/health``` endpoints. I think that's Irrelevant.

Comment: With a filter you don't need to check getRequestURI() twice so you eliminate the risk that it's modified in the meanwhile (e.g. by a forward or a custom request wrapper etc). You can put the creation and destroy of threadlocal in a try-finally in a single method block which is way much more robust.

Comment: Got it. but even if it get's changed in postHandle call. It will clear the ThreadLocal by calling remove, which won't do anything as it's never got set right ?

Comment: @BalusC, I don't see a condition here. Where values set by on request thread in ThreadLocal gets accessed by other request thread and values removed by one request thread will be removed for other request thread as well.

Comment: @BalusC, I am using @Async in service class, Is that possible that context information is not being passed to the thread which is executing, even after using  ```InheritableThreadLocal```